# What is the backend file system used for OpenEBS Jiva and cStor volumes?

Tags: filesystems, storage, openebs

I just got to know about OpenEBS project and I have few doubt regarding the storage engine backend filesystem. What is the backend file system used for OpenEBS Jiva and cStor volumes?

Answer (score 0):

Jiva is all sparse file based.CStor is on COW-based files, can be sparse/real disks.